# How to subscribe to the coinbase websocket?

Tags: coinbase-api

I have referred to the following resources:

https://docs.cloud.coinbase.com/exchange/docs/websocket-overview
https://docs.cloud.coinbase.com/exchange/docs/websocket-channels

After I connect to `wss://ws-feed.exchange.coinbase.com`, I send a subscribe message but it is always rejected by the server.

**Example 1:**

```
To coinbase:
{
    "type": "subscribe",
    "product_ids": [
        "ETH-USD",
        "ETH-EUR"
    ],
    "channels": [
        "level2",
        "heartbeat",
        {
            "name": "ticker",
            "product_ids": [
                "ETH-BTC",
                "ETH-USD"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

From coinbase: {"type":"error","message":"channel is required"}
```

**Example 2:**

```
To coinbase:
{
  "type": "subscribe",
  "channels": [{ "name": "heartbeat", "product_ids": ["ETH-EUR"] }]
}
From coinbase: {"type":"error","message":"channel is required"}
```

**Example 3:**

```
To coinbase:
{
  "type": "subscribe",
  "channels": [{ "name": "status"}]
}
From coinbase: {"type":"error","message":"channel is required"}
```

Basically, I cannot subscribe to any channel.

**Question**> What did I do wrong here?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something is being cached where what you're sending isn't what you think you're sending? Because it worked perfectly for me [here](https://www.piesocket.com/websocket-tester).

With `wss://ws-feed.exchange.coinbase.com` as the url and

```
{
  "type": "subscribe",
  "channels": [{ "name": "status"}]
}
```

as the message.

[image: Working Example]